# How do I select specific filled surface and extrude/blend/operate on it?

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

I have been using Blender for less than a week now. I am actually amazed by the software's capabilities!

Anyway, I have started using Blender for a project where I have automate some of the operations on STL files. With my limited experience of Blender and coding, here is what I have been able to accomplish -

1. Import the stl file
2. Get the dimensions of bounding box.
3. Bisect/cut at a specific distance wherever I want.

[image]

The image shows the manual work which I want to accomplish through coding.

Here's my code -

```
import bpy
import math

# Load STL file
file_path = "D:/Geometry files/STLs and OBJs/match1.2ASCII.stl"
bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=file_path)

# Selecting the stl object you want to work with
bpy.data.objects['match1.2ASCII'].select_set(state=True)

# Selecting EDIT mode
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

# Selecting VERTICES type and selecting them all
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='VERT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

# Naming the active object as obj
obj = bpy.context.object

# Getting bounding box
min_x = min(v.co.x for v in obj.data.vertices)
max_x = max(v.co.x for v in obj.data.vertices)
min_y = min(v.co.y for v in obj.data.vertices)
max_y = max(v.co.y for v in obj.data.vertices)
min_z = min(v.co.z for v in obj.data.vertices)
max_z = max(v.co.z for v in obj.data.vertices)
obj_height = max_z - min_z
cut_height = min_z * 0.5
print(max_z)

# Selection mode - EDIT
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='EDGE')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

# Bisect -                     
bpy.ops.mesh.bisect(plane_co=(23.6438, -40.9733, cut_height), plane_no=(0,0,1), 
                    use_fill=True, clear_inner=True, xstart=0, xend=0, ystart=0, yend=0, flip=False)
```

I have to further do a set of operations on the **filled surface**. But I don't quite understand how do I select that surface?

As I was going through some other questions, I realised that every face/edge/vertex has an ID, if I get that ID, I can select it using the bMesh module (I guess?) and then extrude it. But how do I get that specific filled surface's ID?

I came across this question which mentions similar thing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808840/selecting-a-face-and-extruding-a-cube-in-blender-via-python-api , but here, you have to manually see the ID of the face which seems hardcoding. How do I make it work in my case?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello ! The polygons should be selected in edit mode after the bisect operation is executed

Comment: Hi Gorgious, yes, I realise that. But how do I do that using code?

Comment: Polygons have a `select` attribute you can query for. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html#bpy.types.MeshPolygon.select You might have to go out of edit mode and then back in edit mode for the flag to update

Comment: Umm.. can you be more specific or perhaps give me an example? I am quite unsure how to use it.  I couldn't exactly understand how exactly or what selection criteria is being used while selecting any polygon? I am sorry, but I'm not quite experienced with coding. So stuff like - https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.bisect , I can understand with some efforts.

Comment: Sure, `selected_polygons_indices = [] ; for polygon in obj.data.polygons: if polygon.select: selected_polygons_indices.append(polygon.index)` or `selected_polygons_indices = [p.index for p in obj.data.polygons if p.select]`

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you first create an empty array. And now if any polygon/s are selected, it will add the index of that selected index into that array. However, I tried running it and selecting all the polygons in selected_polygons_indices but it doesn't show/highlight anything, which is a bit weird. Also, selecting the polygons is the challenge in the 1st place which is not being handled by the code :(

Comment: The polygons are already selected after you run the bisect operation

Comment: That's true and I can just plainly extrude it which I did! But I want to make another circular section underneath it and then bridge the loops. That's the problem! (To bridge  them you must join both the objects, and then its not possible to select any of those sections because I don't know the IDs.) Additionally, somewhere in another project I need to locate the meshID of the left-most and right-most cell in mesh so I could place an object over there. And so I am trying to understand indices and select specific polygons/cells.